# How can I debug WebAssembly running on NodeJS in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, webassembly, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a WASM program that I built (Ex. with Emscripten, Zig, or Rust) in VS Code. I will run this program using NodeJS (not in my browser). I want to debug it. Can that be done? If so, what is necessary to enable it?

Comment: I debated writing this answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52333308/11107541), but that didn't feel right, since it was specific to Emscripten and running in browser. I also debated writing this as an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77002246/11107541), but that didn't feel right either, since that was asking for debugging .wat files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug WebAssembly running *on NodeJS* in VS Code if it contains [DWARF](https://dwarfstd.org/) information. You will need to install the [`ms-vscode.wasm-dwarf-debugging`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.wasm-dwarf-debugging) extension.

Full docs on the debugging WASM on NodeJS in VS Code can be found at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_debugging-webassembly including a list of feature caveats comparing to JavaScript debugging.

Here are the release notes that announced this: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_webassembly-debugging.

---

Bonus notes:

- For debugging on web, for Chrome, see https://goo.gle/wasm-debugging-extension and https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/wasm/.
- For debugging webassembly from Rust's `wasm-bindgen`, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_debugging-webassembly.